Minted, custom escape processing
just quick probing question is it possible to make minted to inspect lines and react to it?
Usecase:
# This will print "This is a comment"
echo "This is a comment"
#>This is a comment

echo "This is a shell command"
#>This is a shell command

ls -l
#>total 0
#>-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr 18 00:00 file1
#>-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr 18 00:00 file2

I want to take file with the "#>" prefix used in place where the "executed code" is shown and display it without the "executed comment" as plain text. The "normal" command should be prefixed with "demo@pc / $" prefix
The point is to have executable script file which could be rendered in the latex to tcolorbox "window" as shell execution:
demo@pc / $ # This will print "This is a comment"
demo@pc / $ echo "This is a comment"
This is a comment

demo@pc / $ echo "This is a shell command"
This is a shell command

demo@pc / $ ls -l
total 0
rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr 18 00:00 file1
rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr 18 00:00 file2

Thank You for any hints!
